# I want to show my PDF in partial view where download option are not available its mandatory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show PDF without Download Option. After many search of Google I get some answer but I'm facing a problem in this.

PDF is open in partial View, but there have also Download Option. Is there another option to open Pdf without Download option?

```
 @model Bizzop.Models.MyAccountModel
    @{
       Layout = null;
     }

 <html>
  <head>
    <title>INDEX</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="divPartialView">

    </div>

      <div class="container">
       @if (Model.MyAccountList.Count > 0)
         {
           foreach (var items in Model.MyAccountList)
          {
           <div class="video-row">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick="myPdf(this)"  
               id="@items.PdfName">
              <div class="row">
                @if (items.PdfName == "" || items.PdfName == null)
                {
                  <img src="ImageName"/>
                 }
                else
                 {
                    <img src="ImageName"/>
                }     
           </div>
          </a>
        </div>
           }
        }
    </div>
```

////// This is Ajax code where we pass File name when click the user in anchor 
       tag

```
   <script>
    function myPdf(e) {
        debugger          
        var filen = e.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/MyAccount/MyPdfResult",
            data: { pdfname: filen },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",                
            type: "post",                
            success: function (data) {                   
               SetData(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {

            }  
        });
        function SetData(data) {

            $("#divPartialView").html(data); // HTML DOM replace
        }
    }
</script>
```

/////////// In Controller

```
     public ActionResult MyPdfResult(string pdfname = null)
    {
        string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" 
                        width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";          

        embed += "</object>";
       TempData["Embed"] = string.Format(embed,                    
       VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/TutorialImage/TutorialPdf/"+ 
       pdfname));            
         return PartialView("_Viewpdf", TempData["Embed"]);          
    }
```

/////  where i am create a Partial View

```
    <div class="ancor">
       @Html.Raw(TempData["Embed"])
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just tried it on my side and it worked for me. You need to make sure that your app is allowed to access the pdf file. 
This is my code:

The controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult MyPdfResult(string pdfname = null)
    {
        string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
        embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a>";
        embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
        embed += "</object>";
        TempData["Embed"] = string.Format(embed, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Files/pdf.pdf"));

        return PartialView("_Viewpdf", TempData["Embed"]);
    }
```

The partial view:

```
     <style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyPdfResult", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">View PDF</a>
    <hr />
    @Html.Raw(TempData["Embed"])
}
```

The Index:

```
<div>
@Html.Partial("_Viewpdf");
</div>
```

[image: Like this it worked for me:]

Comment: Its also Open in my side also ..But, i asked that I dont want Download Option in that..