# get pdf file from ftp server and view it without download it in mvc croe

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I got pdf file from ftp server as byte then I converted it to ToBase64String and in front I used iframe. some files appear in the front and others are not.

My code to get file content from ftp server:

```
public byte[] GetFTPFile(string filePathFTP)
        {

            //String filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(hosting.WebRootPath, "downloads") + "/try.pdf" ;
            //String ftpFilePath = "Images/taj123.png";
            WebClient request = new WebClient();
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);


            //NEED TO CHECK IF FILE IS EXIST
            byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(filePathFTP);
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileData);
            return fileData;
        }
```

My code in controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            File file = fileRepo.Find(id);
            //file.Content = System.IO.Path.Combine(hosting.WebRootPath, "downloads") + "/try.pdf";
            file.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(ftpFiles.GetFTPFile(file.FilePath));
            return View(file);
        }
```

My code in cshtml:

```
    <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,@Model.Content" type="application/pdf" class="w-100" style="height:100vh"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Controller:

```
return new FileContentResult(content, "application/pdf");
```

Let me know about the result

Comment: thanks it works but I am showing other information with pdf how can I do it?

Comment: Can you use partial views???

Comment: I didn't use it before

Comment: Check for this answer. It might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343411/i-want-to-show-my-pdf-in-partial-view-where-download-option-are-not-available-it